# Symfony/Doctrine foreingkey at uniqueBy fileds, in sluggable behavior

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, slug

I have the schema:

```
State:
  actAs:
    I18n:
      fields: [state]
      actAs:
        Sluggable:
          unique: true
          uniqueBy: [lang, state]
          fields: [state]
          canUpdate: true
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    country_id:
      type: string(2)
    state:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
```

And I want a unique slug by lang/state, whith this schema works fine, but, now I want a unique slug by lang/state/country_id. So, I add country_id to uniqueBy fields, but that don't work because the sluggable model is on translation table and country_id not.

Is there any idea how can i solved that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What about declaring your own slug builder?

```
State:
  actAs:
    I18n:
      fields: [state]
      actAs:
        Sluggable:
          unique: true
          uniqueBy: [lang, state]
          fields: [state]
          builder: [MyTools, slugify]
          canUpdate: true
```